# Android Studio will be infinitely updated & it does not stop

Tags: android-studio

I'm having trouble with Android Studio.
Sometimes I make changes to my code or add new src to my project
I'm having a serious problem and I have not found any solution to this problem.

Android Studio will automatically and **infinitely** start updating the project and will not stop updating until I close the Android studio or restart.

I mean this update and indexing  will not stop
[image]

Any Solution ?

Comment: You should let it complete...
I would first re-open Android Studio. fix all of the errors in your project (if possible) so that it can achieve a successful build.
Build>>>rebuild project
File>>>invalidate and restart cache

Up-vote my comment if you are a pimp!

Comment: I've done it already and this problem continues @dubDeuce

Comment: Have you tried removing build folder and "Invalidate cache / Restart"? It worked for me

Comment: Unfortunately, I've done all this and this problem is being repeated for 3 days @FaustinoGagneten

Comment: Also you can try updating your Android Studio. Let me know if it works

Comment: Do you mean updating IDE?
Or gradle update @FaustinoGagneten

Comment: I mean an IDE update @AliGhaemi

Comment: My IDE version is 3.1.4 (build 173.4907809) @FaustinoGagneten

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179395/discussion-between-faustino-gagneten-and-ali-ghaemi).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem.

After doing this
problem solved
I changed the gradle version :

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

To

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

And then I upgrade the version of compileSdkVersion to version 27 -> Invalidate cache / Restart